# Array to string conversion error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'm trying to publish a post with register user in my laravel project But this Error happened I don't Know why please help me.

[image]
and my PostController is:

```
 public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
  }

public function index()
{
    $posts=Post::latest()->get();

    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}

public function show(Post $post)
{

    return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('posts.create');
}

public function store()
{

   $this->validate(request(),[
       'title'=>'required',
       'body' => 'required|min:15'
   ]);
   Post::create(request([
        'title' => request('title'),
        'body' => request('body'),
        'user_id' =>auth()->id()
        //auth()->user()->id
    ]));

    return redirect('/');
 }
```

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Please show full error screenshot, which would make some sense.

Comment: What function have an error?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik  Ok! I edite my question

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I shared full screenshot of error please check it.

Comment: in store method i think..  you should have public function store(Request $request)

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten I tested it but don't work for me

Comment: check my answer?

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten sorry!But it don't work

Comment: you are passing array the no.2 passing array(value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

   $this->validate(request(),[
       'title'=>'required',
       'body' => 'required|min:15'
   ]);
   Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'user_id' =>auth()->id()
        //auth()->user()->id
    ]);
return redirect('/');
}
```

of course my code might not work properly but if you could provide me with create method details in post model i can help better

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $model= new Model;
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body' => 'required|min:15'
    ]);

    $model->title= $request->title;
    $model->body= $request->body;
    $model->user_id= auth()->id();
    $model->save();  
    return redirect('/');
}
```